# trying to read iw_statistics but code wont work?

Tags: linux, wireless

I need to read certain statistics from iw_statistics structure, here's the code:

```
struct net_device *dev;
struct iw_statistics *wi_stats = NULL;
dev = first_net_device(&init_net);

  while (dev)
    {
      if (strncmp(dev->name , "wlan",4)==0 )
      {
         if (dev->wireless_handlers-get_wireless_stats(dev) !=NULL ) // <--- here's where the code crashes.
         {
        wi_stats = dev-wireless_handlers->get_wireless_stats(dev);
        printk(KERN_INFO "wi_stats = dev-wireless_handlers->get_wireless_stats(dev); worked!!! :D\n"); 
         }
       }

    }
```

I'm working on linux kernel 2.6.35 and I'm writing a kernel module. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe http://unix.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for your question?

Comment: Adding the error you get from the kernel would be quite useful, but at a guess, I'd say dev->wireless_handlers is NULL. Comparing the interface name is the wrong way to decide if the net_dev is a wifi device or not.

Comment: there's no error, it writes a bunch of stuff on the log file that looks like this:
`Jun 15 06:56:13 ubuntu kernel: [  175.362072] *pde = 00000000 
Jun 15 06:56:13 ubuntu kernel: [  175.364020] Modules linked in: myNetStats(P+) rfcomm binfmt_misc sco bnep l2cap parport_pc ppdev snd_hda_codec_atihdmi arc4 snd_hda_codec_idt snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_pcm ath5k snd_seq_midi radeon mac80211 snd_rawmidi snd_seq_midi_event uvcvideo joydev snd_seq hp_wmi ath 
....`

Comment: you're correct, the problem is that something is pointing to a null.. any idea why ?